# SASS extend inside scope of another class

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS file like so:

```
.fancy_div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  .pretty_text {
    font-size: 8px;
    font-style: italic; 
  }
}
```

then I have another SASS file, where I want to do a similar thing with the `pretty_text` selector.

```
.lame_div {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 3px solid green;
  .ugly_text {
    @extend .pretty_text;
    font-color: #ffd700;
    font-style: bold;
  }
}
```

my goal is to make `.ugly_text` like `.pretty_text` except gold and bold (obviously this is all fake but you get my point).

Of course, if I change the scope of the first, it will work:

```
.pretty_text {
  font-size: 8px;
  font-style: italic; 
}
.fancy_div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

However, this is not a viable solution for several reasons.

Is there a way to extend a class in the scope of another one? Even if it is hacky.

Comment: For future visitors, it would be helpful to see why the output of your first example isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the reason why you can't just modify the code you're extending is because it is part of another library.  However, the answer is no.  Your only option is to modify the original (perhaps submit a patch to the project you're using?).

```
%pretty_text {
    font-size: 8px;
    font-style: italic; 
}

.fancy_div {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    .pretty_text {
        @extend %pretty_text;
    }
}

.lame_div {
    background-color: purple;
    border: 3px solid green;
    .ugly_text {
        @extend %pretty_text;
        font-color: #ffd700;
        font-style: bold;
    }
}
```